# Javascript scope/closures leak

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

Grab javascript closures all parent scope variables, even nothing of it used?

```
function A() {
  var v = 'some heavy content';
  this.foo = function(){
    return function(){
     // I don't use "v" variable here
     // Is there link to it anyway?
     // How to prevent memory leaks like this, if so?
    }
  }
}
```

**Upd:**
Some own research:

```
function A() {
  var v = 'some heavy content';
  this.foo = function(){
    return function(){
      return eval('v');
    }
  }
}
var a = new A();
var foo = a.foo();
a = null;
console.log(foo());//some heavy content
```

Comment: I think, that I can use `A.prototype.foo = function(){}` for it... Or there is not another ways, and I should always use it?

Comment: I don't understand your question. `eval('v')` won't be defined because its parent scope is `window` I believe?

Comment: I think about I want. I want some optimizing here: if closure does not use some variables from parent scope, it can be missed. So I expect `eval('v')` returns `undefined`, but it is not how to `js` works :( It store unnecessary data in the closure scope, even then parent scope already destroyed.

Comment: So are you trying to manually do garbage collect? I don't think you can do that in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

As far as no any answers here..

Best aproach to keep our scopes clean is using correct `prototyping`:

For code above it should be like:

```
function A() {
  var v = 'some heavy content';
}

A.prototype.foo = function(){
  return function(){
    //there is nothing about v here
  };
}
```